# Cannot generate zf2 DoctrineORMModule entities from mapping files

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have zf2 DoctrineORMModule and DoctrienModule installed.  I am trying to use the command tool to create mapping files and generate entities from these mapping files.  (I know this isn't the preferred method, but this is how I'm going to do it.  I have my reasons.)

I have a restful module configured and here is my Doctrine Configuration for this module.

```
// Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'Restful_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Restful/Entities')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Restful\Entities' => 'Restful_driver'
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

I first run

```
doctrine orm:convert-mapping xml /to/my/dest/path --from-database --force
```

This will create my xml file with all the table info.  This part works fine and I can view the xml that it created.  Next I try to run

```
doctrine orm:generate-entities /to/my/dest/path --generate-annotations 
--generate-methods
```

I don't get any errors but also I don't get any results either.  The output from the previous command is.

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

I have tried to read around but havn't found any articles that really solve my problem.  Most say something about not having my annotations/mappings not configured correctly.  But I can dump the entity manager through a controller.

```
var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default'));
```

What do I need to do to get this to generate entities from xml mappings?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us your reasons? I'm curious to know.

Comment: Because I have a huge database schema that I am converting over and I do not want to go back and create all of these by hand.  After generating the entities I can go through and modify them to better suit the project needs.  Plus Doctrine even says to use the tool to accomplish 70% - 80% of the work.  I wasn't trying to be rude by posting that comment.  I just didn't want someone telling me this isn't the preferred method of doing this, when I already know that.  I was trying to keep the question on topic of using the DoctrineORMModule tool and not on my reasons.

Comment: All right, I understand you. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with YAML files and posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525228/zend-framework-2-doctrine-2-cli-generate-entities-from-yaml-each-module/14787595#14787595). I'm sure this will work with xml files as well. Just try to add

```
$driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(array("YOUR_PATH_TO_XML_FILES"));
/* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
$em = $application->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

to the doctrine-module.php.

Comment: This solution worked for me - and I'm using annotations, (so `AnnotationDriver`) and I'm using Silex so I'm not using any `$config` variable. I'm using `$app['orm.em']->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);` - and now my Entity getter / setter generation works perfectly. Thanks ACNB.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the doctrine-module script in vendor/bin? It should be all set up already to read your app's configs.

```
./doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ~/doctrine-entities
```

Comment: Yes that is what I'm using, sorry for not being clear.  I have doctrine-module aliased to doctrine locally.

Answer (score 0):

This "error" occured because you use Annotation Driver for generating. This driver uses your current exist entities and doesnt look at xml. If you want to create Entities from XML - you should send to DI in doctrine configuration section XML driver with need path.

I use another zf2 doctrine module and my DI config has another format, so i cant to send you properly DI example.