# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine 2 CLI generate-entities from YAML each module

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, yaml, zend-framework2

I have clean project ZendSkeletonApplication with integrated Doctrine 2 module "doctrine-orm-module" etc via Composer. Doctrine CLI works from vendor/bin.

I have 'Application' and 'Blog' module, my module config:

```
<?php
namespace Blog;

return array(
  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
      'post' => array(
        'type' => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
          'route' => '/post[/:action][/:id]',
          'constraints' => array(
            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id' => '[0-9]+',
          ),
          'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Post',
            'action' => 'index',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
      'Blog\Controller\Post' => 'Blog\Controller\PostController'
    ),
  ),
  'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
      'blog' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
  ),
  'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
      __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
      ),
      'orm_default' => array(
        'drivers' => array(
          __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
        )
      )
    )
    )
);
```

How to generate Entities from YAML files each module and how to config my modules arrays to use YAML? For example I have my all .yml files in ZendSkeletonApplication/mapping/yml and few .yml files have definitions of Blog module entities and few have definitions of Application module entities.

My entities are in Blog/src/Blog/Entity folder for blog module. All I want its just by one call in Doctrine CLI generate-entities create all Entities each module from all .yml files which are placed in mapping/yml folder? Is it possible? Can anybody provide simple example with doctrine config?

Comment: The Doctrine CLI is located inside `./vendor/bin` and the commands are here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/tools.html#command-overview

Comment: I have error no metadata classes to process. CLI not found my yml files, I tried to config doctrine to use yaml driver but it not helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach quick and dirty approach works for me:

1. Add the following lines to ...vendor\doctrine\doctrine-module\bin\doctrine-module.php:

   ```
   $driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(
        array("YOUR_PATH_TO_YAML_FILES"));
   /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
   $em = $application->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
   $em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

   //...old code...
   /* @var $cli \Symfony\Component\Console\Application */        
   $cli = $application->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.cli');
   ```
2. Now you can this doctrine-module.php on command line interface to call

   ```
    orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=1 PATH_TO_YOUR_ENTITY_CLASSES
   ```

   Be careful with namespaces. The YAML driver expects namespace.entity.dcm.yml to be the the name of the \Namespace\Entity YAML file. The Tool will create PATH_TO_YOUR_ENTITY_CLASSES\Namespace\Entity.php for you.

If you want to use this approach more regularly it might be cleaner to extend Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\CommandGenerateEntitiesCommand along these lines and [add a new command to the cli](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#entity-generation).

Answer (score 2):

Configure your doctrine driver this way on the module.config.php

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'application_entities_yaml'
                //replace Application by your module namespace
            ),
        ),
        'application_entities_yaml' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' .__NAMESPACE__.  '/Yml/')
            //should be where are yours Yml files.
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem make sure that you have generated your entities specifying a namespace for them. You command line for that should be something like this:

```
vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping annotation module/MyNamespace/src/ --namespace="MyNamespace\Entity\\" --from-database
```

Whithout the option *--namespace*, your entities will not be inside a namespace, so the doctrine cannot find your entities.

From here you can make use of annother doctrine commands like orm:generate-repositories (You need to configure your entities specifying the repository names) as follow:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyNamespace\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DoctrineModule` does not officially support entity generation. Use the native CLI of the ORM (`./vendor/bin/doctrine`) to generate your entities, then move them to the required location in your module.

Comment: DoctrineModule does not officially support entity generation?  I tried your tutorial at http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial/#/26 and you generate the schema with `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create`.  I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: @AlexMA let's say that I, as the project maintainer, don't support that functionality :-)

Comment: Okay I think I understand; when I update my schema I should use core Doctrine.